# How to make sure doxygen-style documentation comments aren't missing from C/C++ code?

Tags: c++, c, doxygen, static-code-analysis, linter

I want to run some kind of linter or static code analysis on C/C++ code which gives a warning if there is code with missing documentation, for example a function without its doxygen-style documentation coment. In other words, I want to enforce certain code standards. I had a look into `clang-tidy` and `cppcheck`, but didn't get very far.

To make it a little bit clearer what I'm expecting - from Python, I'm used to something like this:

```
$ cat test.py 
def answer():
    return 42
$ python3 -m pylint test.py 
************* Module test
test.py:1:0: C0111: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
test.py:1:0: C0111: Missing function docstring (missing-docstring)

------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 0.00/10 (previous run: 0.00/10, +0.00)
```

Comment: There's nothing like that for C++ that I ever heard of.

Comment: C++ is the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today. It's syntax and grammar is several orders of magnitude more complicated than Python. Only a real C++ compiler will have any idea where a particular function begins and ends, in a text file that consists of a bunch of ASCII characters. This is why there are not really that many non-compiler tools that can make any sense of C++ code, in order to do the kind of analysis you're looking for. Yes, it might be possible to make some educated guesses, probably based on indentation, but nothing more than that.

Comment: Doxygen itself provides warnings for C++ functions that aren't documented and even for undocumented argument(s) for a documented function. Would that work?

Comment: Yes, I see it print warnings for undocumented functions and parameters when I run it on my code.

Answer (score 6):

Clang has the `-Wdocumentation` option for statically checking Doxygen-style comments. \see https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html.

Also, as @Null mentioned in the comments, the doxygen tool itself will warn of certain documentation issues.

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue recently and I actually used doxygen itself + a custom script to make sure that all the documentation is always present.

In the doxygen config file, enable the following:

```
WARNINGS               = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR      = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = YES

# Do not throw errors on warning
# otherwise, it will stop on first
# error
WARN_AS_ERROR          = NO

# It will write all warnings to a
# warning file. Make sure to
# add this to your gitignore
WARN_LOGFILE           = doxy.warn

# Optional
QUIET                  = YES
```

Now, when you run `doxygen` command, it will write all errors inside `doxy.warn` file.

Now, we are going to parse it and throw error if doxygen fails. Here is the shell script that I use (I don't know much about powershell; so, can't provide a snippet for Windows):

```bash
doxygen

CURRENT_DIRECTORY=$(pwd)

# If doxy.warn file is not empty
if [ -s "doxy.warn" ]; then
    # Remove the current directory from it to
    # make error paths relative and shorter
    # lines for better readability
    cat doxy.warn | sed "s|${CURRENT_DIRECTORY}|.|"

    # Print number warnings
    echo "Total: $(wc -l < doxy.warn) documentation warnings"

    # Exit with error
    exit 1;
else
    echo "Documentation is valid!"
    exit 0;
fi
```